# Mathematica 10 funny bug / Easter egg?

Tags: social-media

I have no idea what is happening here.
I'm using Mathematica 10.

I mistyped "FriendNetwork" as "FriendsNetwork" and got a weird result:

[image]

The option "FriendsNetwork" is not even listed in the help entry for the SocialMedia function.

How is that even possible? I rerun the query multiple times and it gave the same result. I checked my facebook feed and I don't see that image anywhere and I don't know of a friend who would have such a photo.

Can someone try this themselves and check the result?

Comment: Hey, that's my child! No, just kidding. Weirdest bug ever.

Comment: @CameronMurray can you reproduce that?

Comment: Yep. I can reproduce. Same photo.

Comment: LMAO omg this is so funny! I got the same photo.

Comment: "Hey, that's my child!" -- "can you reproduce that?" no, each child is like a snowflake... lol

Comment: hey, I came up with this first, therefore that's MY child

Comment: Let's not use the bugs tag just yet.  If this *is* an Easter Egg it isn't a bug.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard well, you have 100k reputation... I wouldn't even think of arguing with you

Comment: !bizarre behavior. I liked it... :p

Comment: https://xkcd.com/583/

Answer (score 30, accepted):

[image]

The photo is the profile picture of the Facebook page [facebook.com/FriendsNetwork](https://www.facebook.com/FriendsNetwork). The same misunderstanding has been posted here before which is why I know about it but I can't find that post now.

Comment: Haha, this is great!

Comment: Pickett, I deleted it :P

Comment: @Öskå That explains it :)

Comment: I see now. I didn't know I can type a username and it will fetch its profile photo

Comment: LOL, very funny!